# Icon does not appear in iOS app (xcode assets configuration)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, assets

I'am trying put icon in my iOS app following xcode [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/preparing-your-app-for-distribution), but the
the icon does not appear on my device or simulator.

My media assets file on xcode project navigator:

[image: project files]

When selecting the assets file I can see my targets but I can't select my main one, I don't know why. As shown here:

[image: AppIcon config]

In general settings of App I can see the AppIcon linked:

[image: General settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the icons without using asset catalog. I took exam like this [sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Icons/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution is You just need to add icons size 2x and 3x only in iphone app.

Comment: As well? Are you telling me to delete all the others and just leave the 2x and 3x of the iPhone App?

Comment: No need to delete the other icons, you need to add 2x 3x as well.